# How to automatically format picture inserted in workbook via CTRL+V with macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I use PERSONAL.XLSB to run macros in all workbooks. I have a macro that formats selected picture. Every time I paste a picture in a workbook via CTRL+V shortcut I have to press additional shortcut keys to run mentioned macro. Is it possible to somehow connect a macro to the CTRL+V shortcut? Like if these keys were pressed and selected object is an image, then format it? I tried to add a Workbook_Change event to the PERSONAL.XLSB, but it seems it doesn't affect other open workbooks.

```
Sub FormatScreenshot()

Dim r As Object

Set r = Selection

r.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
r.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 2

End Sub
```

Comment: So change your process so that the macro when called by its shortcut pastes the current picture from the clipboard and then does the formatting. Also should the last macro step be save?

Comment: @SolarMike, I would like to connect the macro to the CTRL+V shortcut, without removing it's official purpose. So whenever I copy text, it pastes text. If I make a screenshot and want to paste it, it pastes it with the formatting. No saving needed as last step

Comment: So I would not try to change the behaviour of ctrl+v and use a different one. the macro can paste the image, format it then done.